# Infinite login in msteams-app-lms-meetings reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory

I just want about this msteams-app-lms-meetings reactjs app. I already yarn build on this code and deployed the build files on my server. Also, already added the ms teams app URL on Azure AD account. The problem is the login action is infinite (after I log in, the sign in page will show again, then I login then the sign in will show again, and so and so forth). When I inspected the ms teams app page, this is the error I saw:

Login failed: ClientAuthError: User cancelled the flow.
        at t [as constructor] (AuthError.ts:26:9)
        at new t (ClientAuthError.ts:108:9)
        at Function.t.createUserCancelledError (ClientAuthError.ts:174:16)
        at WindowUtils.ts:46:44

Hoping to get some advice from all of you. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

##### Please check how you added MS team's app URL on Azure AD account.

- Create an **app registration** in your Azure AD tenant like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> New registration***.

[image]

***Go to Authentication tab -> Click Add a platform -> Select Web -> Add MS Teams app URL in the redirect URL field.***

[image]

Make sure **Access tokens** and **ID tokens** checkboxes are selected and Save.

- *Usually*, infinite login loop occurs if you missed giving **Redirect Uri**.
- *If still the issue persists,* try clearing the **cookies** or Sign-In from **Incognito** window.
- **Otherwise**, make use of workarounds mentioned in this **[GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/219#issuecomment-94173643)** blog.

For more information, please **refer** below links:

[Building a MS Teams app using React & FluentUI | by using_namespace_matt | The Startup | Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/building-a-ms-teams-app-using-react-fluentui-82a78b3a7de7)

[Infinite loop between web application and Azure Active Directory | Azure Active Directory Developer Support Team (aaddevsup.xyz)](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/07/infinite-redirect-between-openid-connect-application-and-azure-ad/)